# Node stream line by line close event

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I am receiving a large file from an http post. I need to take each line from this file and insert it into a database. It is much faster to do this by inserting 500 or so lines at a time so this is what I have:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var insertSize = 500;
var records = [];

var reader = readline.createInterface({
  input: inputStream
});
reader.on('line', function(line) {
  reader.pause();
  var entry = line.split('\t');
  if (entry.length != 3) return reader.resume();

  records.push({
    first: entry[0],
    second: entry[1],
    third: entry[2]
  });

  if (records.length < insertSize) return reader.resume();

  database.create(records).exec(function (err) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    records.length = 0;
    reader.resume();
  });
});
reader.on('error', function(err) {
  return res.serverError(err);
});
reader.on('close', function() {
  database.create(records).exec(function (err) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    return res.ok();
  });
});
```

According to the documentation, the `line` and `close` event can still be triggered after `pause()`. I am seeing this happen, as the `close` event is triggered before the `database.create()` finishes in the `line` event. Is there a better way to handle this? `line-by-line` would be good but it can't take a stream as an input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `split` I was able to avoid the issue. The `end` event is not triggered when the stream is paused.

```
var split = require('split');

var insertSize = 500;
var records = [];

readStream.pipe(split())
.on('error', function (err) {
  return res.serverError(err);
})
.on('data', function (line) {
  var _this = this;
  this.pause();
  var entry = line.split('\t');
  if (entry.length != 3) return this.resume();
  records.push({
    first: entry[0],
    second: entry[1],
    third: entry[2]
  });

  if (records.length < insertSize) return this.resume();

  database.create(records).exec(function (err) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    records.length = 0;
    _this.resume();
  });
})
.on('end', function () {
  database.create(records).exec(function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    return res.ok();
  });
});
```